# how to use single radio button with recyclerview in android?

Tags: android, radio-button, android-recyclerview

I have list of data and i want to select only one from it. I have radiobutton and textview in my adapter. Using  notifyDataSetChanged() I am getting single selection but on scroll radio button's value set to "false" and my previous selection is not in same state(true).

Any code or link.

Comment: I'm having the same problem.  Ever find the solution?

Answer (score 1):

You need to save state on your model object which you are inflating in each row of RecyclerView.  Then in the `bindViewHolder(MyViewHolder myViewHolder, int position)` method, you can conditionally set checked state of your radio button like this:

```
        myViewHolder.radioButton.setChecked(myModel.isSelected());
```

Comment: hi,could u post a example code?i dont know how to change the model's selected in onBindViewHolder